# No match for call to .....Some error with lambda function and for_each()

Tags: for-loop, lambda, iterator

I'm trying to use a for_each() to run a function print_a() which takes a string and an int. The function is supposed to print the string and just use the int for formatting purposes. The int is aquired from a function called longestword() which returns the length of the longest word in a map.

Here is the function that contains the first for_each

```
void input_a(vector<string> inlist)
{
    map<string, int> wordcount;

    transform(inlist.begin(), inlist.end(), inserter(wordcount, wordcount.end()), [inlist] (string c){return counter(c, inlist);});
    int longest = longestword(wordcount);
    for_each(wordcount.begin(), wordcount.end(),[longest](pair <string, int> p) {print_a(p,longest);});
}
```

Here is the function longestword();

```
int longestword(map<string, int> list)
{
    int n{1};
    for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),[&n](string s){                %ROW 71
        if (s.length()>n)
        {
            n = s.length();
        }
    });               %ROW 76
    return n;
}
```

Here is the function print_a()

```
void print_a(pair <string, int> entry, int i)
{
    cout << setfill(' ') << right  << entry.first  <<  setw(i) <<  entry.second << endl;
}
```

And here is the error code. The error-lines are marked in the code above with comments.

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                 from wordlist.h:7,
                 from wordlist.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Funct = longestword(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>]’:
wordlist.cc:76:6:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:3884:5: error: no match for call to ‘(longestword(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>) (std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)’
  __f(*__first);
  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
wordlist.cc:71:52: note: candidate: longestword(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>)::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>
     for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),[&n](string s){
                                                    ^
wordlist.cc:71:52: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
```

Sidenote: This is a school assignment and we're not allowed to use regular for- or while loops.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by sending the vector into longestword() instead of the map